# Petrie polygon projection of a hypercube graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to generate the [Petrie polygon projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrie_polygon#The_Petrie_polygon_projections_of_regular_and_uniform_polytopes) of the [8-cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-cube) in Mathematica, like this one:

[image]

I tried using, for example, the [HypercubeGraph function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypercubeGraph.html?q=HypercubeGraph):

```
HypercubeGraph[8]
```

which generates

[image]

As you can tell from the lack of symmetry (notice the shape of the innermost ring, for example), this is not the right projection. I also tried looking at some [GraphPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html) options like `Method`:

```
GraphPlot[HypercubeGraph[8], Method -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
```

but to no avail. How can I generate the Petrie polygon projection of an 8-cube in Mathematica?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I understand this, `GraphData` are based on many nice **custom pre-set layouts**. `Graph` is based on **algorithms that compute layouts**, so computation is not always guaranteed to result in a specially defined geometry.

```
SetProperty[GraphData[{"Hypercube", 8}], VertexStyle -> Red]
```

[image]